# Proof that $x\sin(x)$ is not bounded!

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

I know the question is easy but i just wanted to confirm that my proof is true (thanks to the admins to not close it).  I want to prove that the function $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ is not bounded but  don't go to $+\infty$ when $x$ goes to $\infty$, (Only, using the definition of the limit).

I have constructed this proof and  would like to confirm that it is correct:

We have, $f$ is bounded if and only  if: $\exists M\in \mathbb{R},\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, x\sin(x)\leq M$. Suppose by contradiction that it is true,  if we take $x=2\pi([M]+1)+\pi/2$ we will have

$$(2\pi([M]+1)+\pi/2)\sin(2\pi([M]+1)+\pi/2)=2\pi([M]+1)+\pi/2\geq M$$

Where $[M]$ is the integer part of $M$.

Now, i want to prove that it doesn't go to $\infty$, we have that $\lim \underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{f(x)\rightarrow +\infty}$ if and only if $$\forall A\in\mathbb{R},\exists x_0,\forall x\geq x_0, f(x)\geq A$$

Suppose that it is true, let's choose $A=1$, and $x=2\pi([x_0]+1)\geq x_0$, we get a contradiction because $$2\pi([x_0]+1)(\sin(2\pi([x_0]+1))=0 <1$$

Comment: Consider $x_n = \frac{\pi}2 + 2\pi n$ and $y_n = 2\pi n$.

Comment: @BotnakovN. is there a mistake in my proof ?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah yes i know, i am looking if there is any mistake in my proof?

Comment: By the way, it's not admins who close questions, instead it's ordinary users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct (modulo minor details I might have skipped). Basically what you’re doing is: $\sin(x+k2\pi)=\sin(x)$, so you have
$$ (x_0+2k\pi)\sin(x_0+2k\pi) = (x_0+2k\pi)\sin(x_0)$$
So to prove that this is unbounded you choose an $x_0$ so that $\sin(x_0)>0$ (in your case $x_0=\pi/2$) and you get a sequence that grows to $\infty$. And to prove that it does not go to $\infty$ you take an $x_0$ with $\sin(x_0)\leq 0$ (in your case $x_0=0$), and then get a sequence that does *not* go to $\infty$.

You could even prove: For $\alpha$ you get a sequence $x_n$, $x_n\to\infty$ so that $x_n\sin(x_n)\to \alpha$.

Comment: thanks, but in my proof we don't know what is $x_0$ we just suppose that it exists (following the definition of the limit) to get the contradiction!

Comment: @SarahSora That $x_0$ is not meant in the same way as in the limit definition. This $x_0$.